# Facebook Graph API get page post's attachments

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the url of an image attachment published by a facebook page. The goal is to embed that image in a webpage in order for the website to always display the last image attachment published by the page. I own both website and FB page.

I have yet not grasped all the details on handling Facebook Graph API, but here is what I did so far:

1) in FB developers website, I have created an application, getting its App ID and secret;

2) I used that information to get an access token (just pasted in my browser the following code:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={my-client-id}&client_secret={my-client-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

3) in my website, I have loaded Facebook JS SDK after the body tag; and got also my Facebook page ID from Facebook Page administration;

4) now the real question begins: how can I query Facebook to get the information that I need – the source url of the last published image?

The best result I have gotten so far was by making a getJSON call with the help of jQuery:

```
var fbfeed = $j.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/{my-page-id}/feed?access_token={my-token}&fields=attachments&limit=1');
```

This will get and store a JSON array in the fbfeed variable (please correct me if I'm wrong). One of the keys of that array is called "src" which contains the source url of the attachment – the information I need to embed that picture in my website;

I have the following problems / concerns:
- I have not found the way to retrieve the value of the "url" key – how can I do that? How can I parse the fbfeed variable and extract the value of the "url" key?

– I have concerns with my usage of the access token:

- is it problematic to expose the access token in this way, by using it in a jQuery function? Is it a security risk? If so, can I "mimic" this request but using a server side language such as PHP?
- Will this access token expire (i.e. will I need to repeat step 2 from time to time?). So, imagining that I can get this to work, will I need from time to time to "refresh" the access token?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, the access token should not be exposed in client-side code this way; If you want to do this client-side only, then you should let the viewing user login to your app, so that you can use their own access token. And of course you can make this request server-side as well. // User access tokens can be extended to be valid for up to 60 days, after that you will have to renew it. Better use a page access token to begin with. (That one, again, would of course not belong into any client-side code.)

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to get the information I needed using server-side code, although it may not be the most "clean solution": it will iterate through the last 5 posts of my page until it finds an image and a post url:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed?access_token={access-token}&fields=attachments,link&limit=5';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

for($count = 0; $count < 5; $count++) {

$imagesource =  $json_data['data'][$count]['attachments']['data'][0]['media']['image']['src']; // gets the image url

$postlink = $json_data['data'][$count]['link']; // gets the post url

if (isset($imagesource) && isset($postlink)) {
    // do stuff with the image and post url
    break;
    };

};

// then I can do other stuff as fallback if the image url and post url are not found
```

Comment: Yup!  It was all about that fields=attachments for me!  Thanks for updating your own question with the answer!

Comment: I don't think this will work for posts with *MULTIPLE* images attached, will it? For that you need to use `attachments{subattachments}`.